# Upgrading to an SSD and switching distro on a dualboot

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, grub

I've just bought an SSD, and figured this would be a good time to change my OS configuration on my PC. Currently, I have **one physical drive** and **two partitions**, one on Windows 10 and the other on Ubuntu.

What I want to do is **add the new SSD**, to make **two physical drives**, and follow that by **removing Ubuntu from the old drive** and **installing Manjaro on the SSD**. So at the end, the state of play should be two physical drives, each with one OS on.

At present, the bootloader is handled by Grub through Ubuntu. In terms of reaching this new configuration, is my best bet to remove Ubuntu, switch to Windows' bootloader and then install Manjaro, or install Manjaro first, get it to take over Grub from the Ubuntu partition and then remove Ubuntu?

Is there anything in particular I should be cautious of or bear in particular mind in this process? What's the safest way to proceed?

Comment: Whatever you do make sure you don't delete the ESP (EFI System Partition) that should be in the beginning of the current drive, a small FAT32 partition. Then yes, I would change to the Windows boot manager, boot Windows and remove the Ubuntu partition(s) and expand the Windows main partition. Then add the second drive, boot and install Manjaro in that drive and assure Manjaro's Grub is the first boot device. Then, **you will regret it**: Manjaro is a rolling release and unstable; what works today may not work next week.

Comment: Surely using the Manjaro stable branch there shouldn't be that many issues? I know it's a rolling release model, but it's not bleeding edge like plain Arch.

Comment: There will be issues, many more than with Ubuntu. I use both albeit Manjaro only occasional and for fun. Serious work I do with Ubuntu.